# how can I use gcc to compile a c library so that it contains another library?

Tags: c, gcc

I have a fortran program that calls C wrapper functions that call the actual C functions, which are provided by a software vendor. I compile my C wrapper:

```
gcc -c -o mylib.o -I/home/me/vendor/src -L/home/me/vendor/x64 wrapper.c -l:vendor.a
```

vendor/src contains a header .h file which is #included by my C wrapper. vendor/x64 contains vendor.a, which has the vendor's *.o functions inside it. There are no errors with this compilation and mylib.o is created.
However, when I try to compile my fortran program, I get undefined reference to vendor functions errors:

```
ifort client.f90 main.f90 -L/home/me/wrapper_lib -l:mylib.o
```

Unless I link the vendor.a again:

```
ifort client.f90 main.f90 -L/home/me/wrapper_lib -l:mylib.o -L/home/me/vendor/x64 -l:vendor.a
```

This is different from how it works in my Visual Studio project on Windows, where I am able to compile a static library (mylib.lib) linked to the vendor library, and I can simply link to mylib.lib when compiling my main program. Is there a way to accomplish the same thing with gcc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is "partial linking".

You can do this with `-r` instead of `-c` in your initial command.

It produces a relocatable `.o` as output but (unlike `-c`) *does* link in things that it can resolve (i.e. `vendor.a`)

---

Given the following `.c` files:

```
==> ifort.c <==
void wrapa(void);

int
main(void)
{
    wrapa();
    return 0;
}

==> venda.c <==
void
venda(void)
{
}

==> vendb.c <==
void
vendb(void)
{
}

==> wrapper.c <==
void venda(void);
void
wrapa(void)
{
    venda();
}

void vendb(void);
void
wrapb(void)
{
    vendb();
}
```

---

Here is the build command file:

```
gcc -c venda.c
gcc -c vendb.c
ar crv vend.a venda.o vendb.o

gcc -c wrapper.c
ld -r -o mylib.o wrapper.o -L. -l:vend.a

gcc -o ifort ifort.c mylib.o

nm -go *.o
```

---

Here is the `sh -x` build output:

```
+ gcc -c venda.c
+ gcc -c vendb.c
+ ar crv vend.a venda.o vendb.o
r - venda.o
r - vendb.o
+ gcc -c wrapper.c
+ ld -r -o mylib.o wrapper.o -L. -l:vend.a
+ gcc -o ifort ifort.c mylib.o
+ nm -go mylib.o venda.o vendb.o wrap.o wrapper.o
mylib.o:0000000000000018 T venda
mylib.o:000000000000001f T vendb
mylib.o:0000000000000000 T wrapa
mylib.o:000000000000000c T wrapb
venda.o:0000000000000000 T venda
vendb.o:0000000000000000 T vendb
wrap.o:                 U venda
wrap.o:                 U vendb
wrap.o:0000000000000000 T wrapa
wrap.o:000000000000000c T wrapb
wrapper.o:                 U venda
wrapper.o:                 U vendb
wrapper.o:0000000000000000 T wrapa
wrapper.o:000000000000000c T wrapb
```

Answer (score 1):

> when I try to compile my fortran program, I get undefined reference to vendor functions errors

Well yes.  You compiled a source file with `gcc -c` to produce an object file.  That's perfectly fine, but the whole point of `-c` is that no linking is performed.  You get an object file (such as might be *contained in* a static library), but that does not include anything from any libraries specified on the command line because, again, no linking.

Note also that a single object file is not a library, as the term "library" is conventionally used in the context of linking.  In this sense of the word, you do not *compile* a library at all.  You build one by packing one or more object files into an archive file or by linking object files together into a library binary, depending on what kind of library you want.

Inasmuch as the name of the vendor library suggests that it is a *static* library, it is possible to build a library that includes your wrappers together with the contents of the vendor library, but creating and manipulating static libraries is not a function provided by the compiler or linker at all.  In Linux the central tool for those functions is `ar`, the archiver.  It looks like you want something more or less like this:

```
# Compile the wrapper functions
gcc -c -o wrapper.o -I/home/me/vendor/src wrapper.c

# Add the wrapper functions to a copy of the vendor library, giving
# the result a name of the conventional form
cp /home/me/vendor/x64/vendor.a libmylib.a
ar rs libmylib.a wrapper.o
```

Supposing that that was done in directory `/home/me/wrapper_lib`, you might then compile and link the overall program with

```
ifort client.f90 main.f90 -L/home/me/wrapper_lib -lmylib
```

Comment: If _only_ `mylib.o` references the undefined symbols (i.e. from `mywrapper.c`), would using `-r` work better when building `mylib.o` than `-c`? That is: `gcc -r -o mylib.o -I/home/me/vendor/src -L/home/me/vendor/x64 wrapper.c -l:vendor.a`

Comment: Perhaps so, @CraigEstey.  Partial linking is not a tool that I reach for often.  Or ever, really.  But I think you're right that it would have the effect that the OP thought they would get from their attempt.

Comment: I don't use it much either. I think I've used it once myself. It did seem to be what OP was doing/wanted, so ... That's why I wrote the test case to prove [to myself] that it worked. Personally, I think it's better to just give the _end_ developer the build line that explicitly calls out the vendor library as this is more straightforward. Now that I think of it, I did work for a company that received `bigblob.o` as a deliverable from another company, but that was mostly as an attempt to obscure/protect the company's IP (circa 1982).

Comment: Thank you for giving those clear definitions, precision of language is important. This method makes sense but I hesitate to literally copy vendor.a. The end result is the same I guess but I would rather use the linker to do it.